# Is it possible to disable chmod/chown from sudoers for these specific directories /usr and /etc?

Tags: linux, command-line, chmod, chown

There has been two occasions where I have accidentally chmod-ized 777 the whole direcotry of `/etc` and it has forced me to come to the decision that I'd be better off to do fresh installation of OS (Linux - Ubuntu 14.04 to be specific).  Then few weeks later, to my scare surprise, I accidentally chown-ized to regular user for  whole directory of `/usr`.

I am wondering if it is possible in removing `chmod` and `chown` specifically for only these two directories from `sudoers`, meanwhile allowing files to be controlled by these functions?  (In other words, would I be able to prevent `-R` itself from these two functions for only these two directories?

Thank you.

Comment: You have messed up twice so far, with /etc and /usr. What makes you think next time it won't be /bin, for example? Rather than putting a bandaid on a broken bone, just **be very careful what you do as root.** *Always double-check* a command you execute as root before you do it, whether in a root shell or by using sudo. Linux (and \*nix in general) is built around the assumption that the administrator knows what s/he is doing, so if you say `chmod -R 777 /usr` then that's what you meant, so the tools should do that. The one major bandaid is for `rm -rf /`, because ***nobody** means* to do that.

Comment: That's true.  In other words, in `/etc/sudoers`, the line `%sudo ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL` should be only one user, nothing else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have `sudoers` settings that permit ALL, I don't think it is possible : as for root login, you need to be very careful when `sudoing` some `-R` command.

If `sudoers` explicitly allow `chmod/chown` command, you can achieve this by writing a wrapper script to do the `chmod/chown` and allow this wrapper instead of raw commands.

This way, you can add any control you like in the wrapper.